Why isn't Staged Migration working for my App?
I referred to "What's new in Core Data" in WWDC23, CoreData Documentation and other Posts related Staged Migrations.
I added three new model version through MyAppDataModel, using Hash Modifiers for Versioning.
(Because it caused Error for any version has same version checksum -> "The current model reference and the next model reference cannot be equal")
<V1 -> V2>:
I added dateInTime attribute to Book Entity as LightweightMigration in MyAppDataModel.
<V2 -> V3>:
I want to set dateInTime attribute with Date type value, which is made by changing date attribute from String type to Date type.
And then want to set date attribute as nil.
As far as I know, Once NSStageMigrationManager is set to persistentStoreDescription's option and just call persistentContainer.loadPersistentStore, Staged Migration will work.
But my staged migration isn't work...
I'm wondering if there is something wrong with my code.
Any chance, If you need more information about my situation, please let me know!
guard let packageURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "MyAppDataModel", withExtension: ".momd") else {
    fatalError("Failed to find file matched with name")
}
let v1ModelURL = packageURL.appending(component: "MyDataModel.mom")
let v2ModelURL = packageURL.appending(component: "MyDataModel 2.mom")
let v3ModelURL = packageURL.appending(component: "MyDataModel 3.mom")

guard let v1Model = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: v1ModelURL),
      let v2Model = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: v2ModelURL),
      let v3Model = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: v3ModelURL) else {
    fatalError("Failed to find model related to the URL")
}

let v1ModelReference = NSManagedObjectModelReference(model: v1Model, versionChecksum: v1Model.versionChecksum)
let v2ModelReference = NSManagedObjectModelReference(model: v2Model, versionChecksum: v2Model.versionChecksum)
let v3ModelReference = NSManagedObjectModelReference(model: v3Model, versionChecksum: v3Model.versionChecksum)

let v1ToV2 = NSCustomMigrationStage(migratingFrom: v1ModelReference, to: v2ModelReference)
// OR let v1ToV2 = NSLightweightMigrationStage([v1Model.versionChecksum])
v1ToV2.label = "V1 to V2: Add dateInTime attribute"
let v2ToV3 = NSCustomMigrationStage(migratingFrom: v2ModelReference, to: v3ModelReference)
v2ToV3.label = "V2 to V3: Change date attribute type for all entities"

v2ToV3.willMigrateHandler = { migrationManager, currentStage in
    guard let container = migrationManager.container else {
        fatalError("Failed to otionalize container")
    }
    
    let context = container.newBackgroundContext()
    context.performAndWait {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Book")
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "date != nil")
        
        do {
            var fetchedResults: [NSManagedObject]
            fetchedResults = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
            
            for book in fetchedResults {
                guard let dateWithStringType = book.value(forKey: "date") as? String else {
                    fatalError("Failed to Cast as String")
                }
                let formatter = DateFormatter()
                formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy.MM.dd E"
                guard let dateWithDateType = formatter.date(from: dateWithStringType) else {
                    fatalError("Failed to parse as Date")
                }
                book.setValue(dateWithDateType, forKey: "dateInTime")
                book.setValue(nil, forKey: "date")
                
            }
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            fatalError("Failed to Fetch Or Save: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
        
let migrationManager = NSStagedMigrationManager([v1ToV2, v2ToV3])
let persistentContainer = NSPersistentContainer(name: "MyAppDataModel")

guard let storeDescription = persistentContainer.persistentStoreDescriptions.first else {
    fatalError("Failed to get a first desciption")
}
storeDescription.setOption(migrationManager, forKey: NSPersistentStoreStagedMigrationManagerOptionKey)

persistentContainer.loadPersistentStores { description, error in
    if let error = error {
        fatalError("Failed to load persistent store: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}


I've also been trying to figure out NSStagedMigrationManager, and I've gotten mine to work with similar code to yours. Could you explain in your question exactly what isn't working? Are you getting some error? Or what? Also, your code sample shows reference to customStage, which isn't declared anywhere. Maybe it's supposed to be v2Tov3?

Thank you for your comment, and sorry for the late reply!
First, the customStage is actually v2ToV3. I made a mistake when moving my code
I wasn't getting an error, but nothing happened after executing the code, so I'm not sure what the issue is.
If you could share your code or provide any additional details, I would really appreciate it. I'd like to try the staged migration again, as I'm still unable to resolve the issue....

My code is in a repository I've been working on here, which is just a lot of convenience functions and variables to streamline a lot of the boilerplate. Your code should work, though, so I'm going to write an answer here with a few things that stand out to me after reviewing yours... hopefully the solution is in there somewhere!

Your setup looks correct, but after looking at it a few times I can see a few places that might be the culprit, or places to add logging to help debug the situation.
First, I'd like to call out something you're doing very right--
let v1ToV2 = NSCustomMigrationStage(migratingFrom: v1ModelReference, to: v2ModelReference)
// OR let v1ToV2 = NSLightweightMigrationStage([v1Model.versionChecksum])
v1ToV2.label = "V1 to V2: Add dateInTime attribute"

In my testing, I've found that NSLightweightMigrationStage is confusing and frustrating. NSCustomMigrationStage(migratingFrom:to:) without a willMigrateHandler or didMigrateHandler is the same as a lightweight migration stage, but you get to explicitly state the "From" and "To" versions. NSLightweightMigrationStage's init function doesn't have good documentation to tell us how it's working, so I avoid using it entirely. NSCustomMigrationStage does lightweight AND custom migrations, so I'd say stick with that.
Now, to a few places that see as possible culprits for your migration not working:
1 - The Fetch Request:
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "date != nil")

I didn't notice this at first, but it's possible that the way NSPredicate format works might be messing you up. Try this:
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K != nil", #keyPath(Book.date))

2 - NSPersistentStoreDescription setup
This probably isn't the problem, but it can't hurt to double-check.
// you already have this:
storeDescription.setOption(migrationManager, forKey: NSPersistentStoreStagedMigrationManagerOptionKey)
// but you could try adding these:
storeDescription.shouldMigrateStoreAutomatically = true
storeDescription.shouldInferMappingModelAutomatically = true

I think those extra options are true by default, but I like to explicitly add them just in case. I think they're necessary for the staged migration to take place.
3 - Add lots of logging!
Whatever the cause of the problem is, one good way to figure out where it's going wrong is to put a lot more logging in to see what's happening and what's not.
First, I'd put at least one log statement at the very beginning of the willMigrateHandler to make sure it's being performed at all. The fatalError statements are fine for making sure required variables exist, but you'd also want to make sure the overall function is being called.
Second, put some logging statements after performing the fetch request to see if any results were returned. It's possible the fetch request is getting zero results, which would certainly cause the behavior you're noticing (nothing happening!).
Third, at the end of the for loop, maybe just put a log in there to see what the book is and what the date is being set to.
4 - Check the Existing Store
I've found it's fairly difficult to get the testing environment set up correctly to test a staged migration, so I want to make sure you have yours set up right, as well. Specifically, that the source store is actually set up with the earlier version of your model. This is important, because one reason a migration wouldn't happen is because the store you're opening is already configured for the latest model version.
Try running this code BEFORE you create your PersistentContainer. You will need the URL for the PersistentStoreDescription.
let storeUrl: URL = <#where the SQLite files are located#>
let storeMetadata = try! NSPersistentStoreCoordinator
    .metadataForPersistentStore(type: .sqlite, at: storeUrl)

let models: [(String, NSManagedObjectModel)] = [
    ("MyDataModel", v1Model),
    ("MyDataModel 2", v2Model),
    ("MyDataModel 3", v3Model),
]

let configuration: String? = <#configuration name or nil#>
for (name, model) in models {
    let isCompatible = model.isConfiguration(withName: configuration, compatibleWithStoreMetadata: storeMetadata)
    if isCompatible {
        print("Store is version \(name)")
    } else {
        print("Store is not version \(name)")
    }
}

If you get the message Store is version MyDataModel 3, then the reason the migration isn't happening is because the SQLite store is already using version 3.

That's all I've got for now. My money is on the NSPredicate, but I'm not certain. It's worth trying the logging statements before changing that predicate to see if you can find where the problem is actually occurring.
Good luck!
PS: small efficiency pointer, too-- move that DateFormatter outside of the for loop so you're not creating a new one for each Book, or use a FormatStyle. Creating a new DateFormatters for each Book is an expensive and unnecessary operation.

Thank you for your detailed explanation! I updated my code based on your advice, but unfortunately, it's still not working. I found that neither willMigrationHandler nor didMigrationHandler are being called. However, the closure of persistentContainer.loadPersistentStores is being executed. When I log inside this closure and print the description parameter, it prints well. Why is the willMigrationHandler not being called?
I attach my project, here!

@user15256852 I'm Sorry to hear it didn't work. I don't know if I'll have time very soon to dig into your project, but I will try eventually. In the meantime, I have one last question-- how sure are you that the SQLite store as it exists when the app is launched is set up with the old version of your data model? Is it possible there's no data to migrate, or that the data model is already in the current (version3) version?

Thank you so much for your help so far! I will try again  on my end as well.
Regarding your last questions, I can confirm that the data is definitely available. I also set the model version to Version 3 through MyDataModel 3 > File Inspector > Model Version > Current. I initially thought the issue might be with the version setting, but no matter which version I selected, the process still didn’t work as expected, so I didn’t suspect any issues with the version. (Below, continuing)

However, after reviewing your suggestions, I now realize that I need to double-check everything — from the current version setting to verifying the data availability.
I won’t be able to start the migration right away, but once I do, I will update you on the progress!
Thank you again for your support.

Have you ever encountered the error 'The current model reference and the next model reference cannot be equal'? To fix the error, I added a Hash Modifier for each model. I think this might be the cause of the problem, but I’m not sure how to fix the error without adding the Hash Modifier...

@user15256852 I'm not familiar with that error, but it makes me wonder if my previous question might require more testing. I'm going to update my answer with some more code... might take a little while, but I'll comment again and let you know when it's ready.

Alright. Please take a look at #4 in the answer above when the edits are approved :-)
